# Split chars using regex

Tags: regex

Hi I have decided to learn some regex and now I have a problem.

I have lots of lines that looks like:

```
001000FF - D6 55 17 C4 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 01 02 C4 FF
```

So i decided to split them using regex, but It does not work as I expected. So my regex looks like:

```
(^[a-zA-Z0-9])(\b(?:[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,2}\ ){15}[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,2}\b)
```

I want it to split this into 2 groups first would contain 001000FF second the rest (without - of course). Well second part of regex ((\b(?:[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,2}\ ){15}[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,2}\b)) works when it is on its own i am getting second group. So what needs to be changed to get two groups as i described?

Comment: Currently your first group is just a single character afther the start of the string. Therefor it won't find you word-boundary right after. Would [`^([A-Z\d]+) - ([A-Z\d]{1,2}(?: [A-Z\d]{1,2}){15})$`](https://regex101.com/r/09LTtU/1) be what you are after?

Comment: You can even use `^(\S+) - (.+)` if the lines are all in the same format and you just need to get the values correctly.

Comment: you could use `cut` too :)

Comment: Wojtku, are you trying to get something like https://ideone.com/ghrZAK ? What is your tool/programming language?